# How to apply fields validation in C#?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am making desktop application. So, I have to apply checks on combo boxes and text fields.

Is there any built in validation component in *C#*? If not then please tell me how to use validation in window application form with errors logo?

Regards
Touseef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

---

Refer to the following article:

[Error Provider in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/UseErrorProvider03082007210138PM/UseErrorProvider.aspx)